# Is it possible to put audio into 'phone' mode?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

By this I mean, use the speaker and phone microphone but don't use the speaker in the handsfree style.

So the use case is:
1. User is listening to the app via the phones speaker
2. They wish to put the phone to their ear so they choose an option which changes the audio to be as if they were talking on the phone (i.e. non-hands free mode)

Does this make sense? Or should this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord];
```

This will route all audio output to the receiver--"the small speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call". See [Audio Session Programming Guide: Configuring the Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/audio/conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW2) for more details.